# Create a table column as a sum of two columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, and one of the columns is total_price, which stores the sum of prices of items which are stored in another table. I want to know how to do this in SQL. I want the total price column to calculate the sum of prices automatically and store in its column. In other words, I need a column which sums the required values and stores it by default.

Example:

Line item table has a quantity,pid and total price field.

Product table has a pid and price field.

The total price field in line item table should store (lineitem.quantity*product.price) value.

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` for each table and more info on wanted output.

Comment: Normally, you would just do this with an aggregation query when you need the data.  There typically isn't a need to store this information separately.

Comment: My total price is quantity * price of items.Total price field can't hold anything else other than this.So it would be more meaningful if I store this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to store it, you could still create a trigger.

```
create trigger UpdateMyColumn before insert on [yourtable] for each row
begin set new.Col3 = Col1 * Col2;
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this query to create a table with col3 as sum of col1 and col2:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50),
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [Qty] [float] NULL,
    [total]  AS ([Price]*[Qty])
) ON [PRIMARY]
```